# expanding.apply in polars

Tags: python, python-polars, rust-polars

In `pandas` I could call `data.expanding(min_periods=1).apply(lambda_func)` to call a func on expanding or a cumsum-like view.

How to do the same thing with polars? I could only find `rolling_apply` or `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

From `polars>=0.13.36` you can run `cumulative_eval` to run polars expressions on a cumulative increasing window.

Note that you should not use this for an aggregation like `sum` as this will have `O(n^2)` complexity.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

df.select([
    pl.col("values").cumulative_eval(pl.element().first() - pl.element().last() ** 2)
])
```

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌────────┐
│ values │
│ ---    │
│ f64    │
╞════════╡
│ null   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -3.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -8.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -15.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -24.0  │
└────────┘
```